# Modeling distributions

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance

Suppose I am studying a unimodal, interval-leveled variable $Y_i$ that measures e.g. individuals' positions on a (-$\infty$,+$\infty$) continuum. 
Then, I noticed that for different sub-categories of individuals the distribution of $Y_i$ is different. for instance for category C, $Y_i|C$ is flatter, with less density mass around the mean and heavier tails, while for individuals in category D, $Y_i|D$, the distribution has a mass around the mean value and only few outliers.

The mean of the two distributions is about the same, and thus a regression coefficient would be non-informative. In fact, that's not what I am looking for. My question is about how testing the difference between these two distributions. Specifically, is there a way to model —i.e. in a regression framework— the thickness of the tails?

Comment: If you are  interested in testing $H_0:\;\;f(Y_i\mid C) \equiv f(Y_i\mid D)$ you could simply use a two sample  K-S test. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test are you looking for somwthing else?

Comment: This would allow me to test whether the two distributions are different or not. That would be a start. But I would like a method to estimate e.g. whether and to what extent a certain individual variable is systematically correlated with flatter tails.

Comment: Could you tell us some context? Why are you interested in the tail? Also, show us some plots, maybe qqplots.